# I cannot install Tensorflow Version 1.15 through pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have checked my `pip` version and got the following output:

```sh
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in 
./anaconda3/envs/runlee_python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.1)
```

I have a specific situation in which I have to use version 1.15 of Tensorflow, but when I try to install it, it seems like it can‘t find this specific version.

```sh
pip install tensorflow==1.15
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15
```

I can also not find version 1.15 when listing all available options.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why install the package through pip if you're already using Conda?

Comment: check your pip version >=19

Comment: if you are using normal cmd then type pip install tensorflow==1.15 else for anaconda cmd  conda install tensorflow==1.15

Comment: @AMC it is not matter what i use conda ...

Comment: @JaiMahesh it is problem with python version () ... thanks your comment

Comment: @runRyan _it is not matter what i use conda ..._ What? Yes, it absolutely does matter. See, for example: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You are using python 3.8, which was not officially supported when tensorflow was at version 1.15. You can also check on pypi, there are no files available for cp38, even for [2.10](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/#files) Onle the versions listed by your command have a cp38 whl file available, see [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0rc1/#files)

Since you have conda, simply create a virtual env with the required version

```
conda create -n tf python=3.7
```

then install tensorflow in this env

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, then feel free to accept it

Comment: Better would be to include all known requirements from the start, e.g., `conda create -n tf15 python tensorflow=1.15`. Conda will figure out the latest Python version for you.

Comment: Thanks. You also need a recent version of pip.

Comment: Hi, I was facing the same problem so, I executed the above mentioned command and installed the environment. now how can I run command in that environment?

Comment: you need to activate the environment with `conda activate tf`

Comment: Can I just add that installing an older version of tensorflow is possible if one uses alternative links but usually leads to catastrophic results. This answer really gets to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 7):

You must be using python <=3.7 to install Tensorflow 1.15. See the [pypi release page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.5/). Assuming you are and you still get this issue, upgrading from `pip-20.1.1` to `pip-21.0.1` fixed it for me. Try upgrading pip.

Comment: Python 3.7 would work. Not necessary for Python 2.7.

Comment: Xhengyang is right - works with 3.7. But the newer pip is needed.

Comment: I’m so sorry this was a typo, will edit. To clarify: you need 3.7 or lower, 3.8 is not supported by 1.15

Comment: Take note this only applies to official wheels though. Nvidia [has](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040354322) [supposedly](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Install-TensorFlow-1-15-for-NVIDIA-RTX30-GPUs-without-docker-or-CUDA-install-2005/) moved 1.15 forward. There are lots of [community](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels) works too.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This version of python**

```
conda install python==3.6.13
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your python3 version, it should be satisfied based on the supported versions in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements)

if you need to change your python3 version, you can follow the below steps:

1. Install **pyenv**, using any package manager you use, here *homebrew*

   `brew install pyenv`
2. Add the following lines to your shell configuration file, (~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zshrc):

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

   eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

   eval "$(pyenv init -)"
   ```
3. Install the required python3 version, in my case, I had 3.12 but I had to install max 3.11:

   `pyenv install 3.11.0`
4. Set Global or Local python3 version,
   for global (which I recommend)

   `pyenv global 3.11.0`
   or for local
   `pyenv local 3.11.0`
5. To verify the global python3 version:

   `pyenv versions`
   and you should see,

> system
> * 3.11.0 (set by /User/YOUR_USER/.pyenv/version)

Then first run:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

and now you can install the **tensorflow**

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```