# How do I get Tensorflow 1.8?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I'm trying to use Speaker-Diarization from GitHub(link below), but it requires Tensorflow 1.8 through 1.15. so I have been scrolling through TensorFlow's official website, and I can't find anything linked to previous versions , so I am not sure if my python 3.8 would work? or how to pip Tensorflow 1.8 1.15?

[Speaker-Diarization](https://github.com/taylorlu/Speaker-Diarization)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot install Tensorflow Version 1.15 through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491893/i-cannot-install-tensorflow-version-1-15-through-pip)

Answer (score 1):

Just install it through pip

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```